# PyTest deprecation: 'junit_family default value will change to 'xunit2'

Tags: python, pytest, circleci

I'm getting deprecation warning from my pipelines at `circleci`.

**Message**.

```
/home/circleci/evobench/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/junitxml.py:436: PytestDeprecationWarning: The 'junit_family' default value will change to 'xunit2' in pytest 6.0.
```

**Command**

```
- run:
    name: Tests
    command: |
      . env/bin/activate
      mkdir test-reports
      python -m pytest --junitxml=test-reports/junit.xml
```

How should I modify command to use xunit?
Is it possible to a default tool, as it is mentioned in the message?
I mean without specyfing xunit or junit.

Here's full [pipeline](https://github.com/piotr-rarus/evobench/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run your command in this ways.

### with xunit2

`python -m pytest -o junit_family=xunit2 --junitxml=test-reports/junit.xml`

### with xunit1

`python -m pytest -o junit_family=xunit1 --junitxml=test-reports/junit.xml` or

`python -m pytest -o junit_family=legacy --junitxml=test-reports/junit.xml`

[This here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#junit-family-default-value-change-to-xunit2) describes the change in detail:

> The default value of junit_family option will change to xunit2 in
>   pytest 6.0, given that this is the version supported by default in
>   modern tools that manipulate this type of file.
>
> In order to smooth the transition, pytest will issue a warning in case
>   the --junitxml option is given in the command line but junit_family is
>   not explicitly configured in pytest.ini:
>
> ```
> PytestDeprecationWarning: The `junit_family` default value will change to 'xunit2' in pytest 6.0.   Add `junit_family=legacy` to your
> ```
>
> pytest.ini file to silence this warning and make your suite
>   compatible.
>
> In order to silence this warning, users just need to configure the
>   junit_family option explicitly:
>
> ```
> [pytest]
> junit_family=legacy
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In your pytest.ini file add the following line:

```
junit_family=legacy
```

If you want to keep the default behavior of the `--junitxml` option. Or you can accept the new version, `xunit2` but not explicitly defining the junit_family variable.

Essentially what the warning is saying is you are giving the `--junitxml` option in your

```
run           
  name: Tests
```

section not specifying the junit_family variable. You need to start to explicitly defining it to remove the warning or accept the new default.

[This thread goes into more details about where to find the .ini file for pytest.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html)

Comment: How can I dump artifacts without junit? I know all about quirks to use junit. I was wandering how can I use xunit, as I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

For official statement/documentation about moving from **xunit1** to **xunit2** read: [docs.pytest.org](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#junit-family-default-value-change-to-xunit2)

Also if your project contains ***pytest.ini*** file you can set *junit_family* usage directly from the file like:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
minversion = 6.0
junit_family=xunit2
junit_suite_name = Pytest Tests
addopts = -ra -q -v -s --junitxml=path/to/pytest_results/pytest.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers pretty much covered the means of specifying the junit family, either within pytest.ini or at the commandline with an ini option override.

It's worth looking at the differences between xunit1 and xunit2 for a concrete xml file. Doing a quick spot check on the differences I found these differences show in the image below for the following test module...

```py
# test_stub.py

import sys
import pytest

def test_pass():
    assert True

def test_fail():
    assert False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(pytest.main([__file__] + sys.argv[1:]))
```

Pytest was ran under three separate configurations (which match the vertical order in the image)

```bash
# Default execution
pytest test_stub.py --junit-xml=out.xml 
pytest test_stub.py --junit-xml=out_xunit2.xml -o junit_family=xunit2

# Junit prefix execution
pytest test_stub.py --junit-prefix=FOOOP --junit-xml=out_prefix.xml
pytest test_stub.py --junit-prefix=FOOOP --junit-xml=out_prefix_xunit2.xml -o junit_family=xunit2

# Junit suite execution
pytest -o junit_suite_name=SUITE test_stub.py --junit-xml=out_suite.xml
pytest -o junit_suite_name=SUITE test_stub.py --junit-xml=out_suite_xunit2.xml -o junit_family=xunit2
```

All of the diffs pretty much highlight the fact that xunit2 omits the `file` and `line` attributes that showed up previously in xunit1. The other diffs were merely timestamp differences. Both `junit_suite_name` and `junit-prefix` behave as before.

[image: junit xml differences]

Another major difference is that for some reason `record_property` has been deprecated under the xunit2 schema.

```
PytestWarning: record_property is incompatible with junit_family 'xunit2' (use 'legacy' or 'xunit1')
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.junitxml.record_property